# Fortran derived type constructor defined though C function (II)

Tags: c, binding, fortran

Following question [Fortran derived type constructor defined though C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271552/fortran-derived-type-constructor-defined-though-c-function), I came up to this non working example, with gfortran 4.9:

```
module my_module
  use iso_c_binding
  type, bind(c) :: my_double
     real(c_double) :: x
     real(c_double) :: y
  end type my_double
  interface my_double
      procedure my_module_fortran_new_my_double
  end interface
  interface
     type(my_double) function my_module_fortran_new_my_double (v) bind ( c )
       use iso_c_binding
       import :: my_double
       real (c_double), intent(in) :: v
     end function my_module_fortran_new_my_double
  end interface
end module my_module

program main
  use my_module
  type(my_double) x
  x = my_double(12)
end program main
```

Following the previous question [Fortran derived type constructor defined though C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271552/fortran-derived-type-constructor-defined-though-c-function), the module defintion works fine. However, the defined constructor is not recognized by my compiler.

Here is the compiler output:

```
$ gfortran -std=f2008 test.f90 -o test.o -c
test.f90:22.6:

  x = my_double(12)
      1
Error: No initializer for component 'y' given in the structure constructor at (1)!
```

This does seem that my used defined constructor is not taken into account. Could someone help me understanding what I have done wrong (again) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a specific constructor to match

```
my_double(12)
```

there must be a procedure with interface

```
type(my_double) function something(i, ...) ...
   integer ... :: i
   ..., optional, ... :: ...
end function
```

as the single component source given is of type `integer`.

The only non-default specific constructor provided is the one with one non-optional component source of type `real(c_double)`.

To solve, two approaches:

- add a specific procedure which takes a default integer; or
- specify an appropriate argument to the non-default constructor.

For this latter:

```
x = my_double(12._c_double)   ! c_double from intrinsic iso_c_binding
```

It's worth noting why this problem comes about.  You may happily try

```
x = my_double(12,13)  ! Using the normal constructor
x = my_double(12)     ! Using the normal constructor if default
                      ! initialization applies for component y
```

as with the implied constructor there is conversion of the source term (following the rules of intrinsic assignment) to the type/parameters of the component itself.  Such conversion does not apply in the case of resolving generics.

Comment: Thank you. I am too much used to C++ implicit convertions.

Comment: I've just added some detail on the implicit type conversion.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll add constructors for build-in types.